# Hosting an Azure App Service on an apex/naked domain

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, azure, azure-web-apps

I have created an Azure App Service site which is moving to production.

I am having some problems with the fact that Azure can only handle SSL/TLS for subdomains.

My subdomain `www.abc123.com` is currently using a `CNAME` record to point to the App Service, this works well and SSL works flawlessly.

However the apex/naked domain `abc123.com` can't use a `CNAME` record as email is handled by gmail and the `CNAME` root record would interfere with the `MX` record (?).

I have tried adding an `A` record for `abc123.com` to point to my App Service IP address, this forwards traffic but gives an SSL error as Azure requires a CNAME for SSL to function.

I have made a messy workaround which is an `A` record for `abc123.com` pointing the IP of an Apache server serving other sites, this server uses the `.htaccess` to redirect to the `www.abc123.com` domain.

Is there any way to handle this natively in Azure? Or a service that would perform the same function that my Apache server is doing? Or even a way to add a CNAME and have email still work for the domain?

Answer (score 3):

A clarification first, App Services do support SSL for apex domains using an A record, however the free certificate offering in app service does not currently support this. You can follow the uservoice item for this [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/38981932-add-naked-domain-support-to-app-service-managed-ce)

You can however use an SSL certificate for the apex A record if you supply your own SSL cert, either using an Azure App Service Certificate (this is a separate product in Azure) or purchasing an SSL cert from any other provider and [importing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate) this into your app service.

Comment: Another option for certificates is to use Let's Encrypt.  You can generate a free one quite easily.  Two catches: 1) You have to authenticate using one of their pre-canned methods.  2) It has to be renewed every 90 days.

Comment: @GaretJax very true, details on one way to do this are here - https://samcogan.com/lets-encrypt-certificates-in-azure-with-acmebotot/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a service like http://wwwizer.com/.  It performs a naked redirect to www and it has a static IP.  I know it isn't great, but it might help you.